# Room: observe LiveData to trigger SyncAdapter

Tags: android, android-room

I want to request a sync of my sync adapter every time a change happens to some of my data. Having LiveData I wonder if the correct way would be to bind a observer to the data within the application lifecycle.

Does anyone know what the "official" way of doing this is?

Comment: I'm having trouble with this as well, room isn't triggering the sync adapter to run properly.